# typo3 solr search result link without L Parameter

Tags: solr, typo3

I use the TYPO3 Extension solr 7.0.1 under TYPO3 8.7. Unfortunately, the L = 0 parameter is always appended to the links in the search results. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1):

First a question, what is the problem with that? It should certainly not harm since L=0 is neutral for page resolution - it is the default for that parameter.

If you stil don't like it you have two solutions:

1) If you are using RealURL you just need to properly map this parameter

```
'preVars' : array(
                    'GETvar' => 'L',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                    ),
                    'valueDefault' => '0',
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
```

2) If you really want to eliminate it from solr indexer you just need this TS setup

```
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.pages.fields.url.typolink.additionalParams >
```

But thing about it, when you need to add multilanguage setup in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I now have entries from tx_news also in the search results, here is the L = parameter unfortunately also still in the URL. What do I have to do to remove this?

Comment: check the tt_news example confuguration end remove the `&L= `parameter. Most probably something like this will work:

`plugin.tx_solr.index.queue.tt_news.fields.url.typolink.additionalParams = &tx_ttnews[tt_news]={field:uid}`